# aiflow max active dag runs reached

Tags: python, airflow

As soon as Airflow starts, None of the dag runs for a particular dag are executed and reaches maximum active dags. Even after setting the dag run state to success, Scheduler doesn't seem to move the newly scheduled task to execution state. All the active dag runs remain in 'running' state. This happens for some dags alone. Can someone please help on this?

Comment: You seem to be describing the state as described by the web server. Please confirm your scheduler is running and healthy.  What is your config setting for maximum number of DAD runs?

Answer (score 2):

this problem happened to me too.
I checked the scheduler's log, it said:
[the log.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGwA6.png)

my DAG's `max_active_run` is set to 1. so, there must be another Dagrun still running while I trigger the DAG manually.

Yes! so I marked the previous DAGrun FAIL, then trigger, it start to running.
[where I marked fail on airflow webUI.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipUSB.png)

It really sucks because I need 10 reputation for posting images.

Answer (score 0):

Check the instance task detail to find out what is the problem which is preventing the DAG from being executed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This means that the **dag_concurrency** is set to a smaller number of concurrent task than you are trying to use. there is a file called airflow.cfg where you can change some execution configurations, one is the **dag_concurrency**, it is probably set to '6' increase it to your necessity, just make sure it doesn't exceed the number of **parallelism** that may cause problems.